# prolog: how to tell with global_cardinality that a list has at least N element that equals M (M,N are integer)

Tags: prolog, constraint-programming, clpfd, sicstus-prolog

For example: I have some variable: A,B,C,D, and a condition: in [A,B,C,D] list there must be **at least** twice the number 2.
I can only use [global_cardinality/2](http://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/Combinatorial-Constraints.html#index-global_005fcardinality_002f_005b2_002c3_005d-_0028clpfd_0029-3399) combinatorial constraint.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it was a fairly stupid question. The solution is for example:
global_cardinality(VarList, [1-_,2-M]), M >= 2.
So we haven't got any constraint on how many 1 number the VarList has, but we give the number of number 2, that is M, and let M be greater than 2.

Comment: Fine, except ">=" is not a constraint, but a Prolog test. Replace it by "#>=" and everything should be fine.